# undefined method `decorate' for #<Assignment::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, decorator

I'm trying to implement my first decorator for my view. I'm running into an issue though. When I try to render the view I get the title error `undefined method "decorate" for #<Assignment::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do? Any help would be great. Here is my code.

### Assignment decorator:

```
class AssignmentDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all
  decorates :assignment

  def status
    if finished
      "Finished"
    else
      "Waiting"
    end
  end
end
```

### Pages Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :verify_account!, only: :dashboard

  def home; end

  def dashboard
    @assignments = current_account.assignments.all.decorate
    @invitation = Invitation.new
  end
end
```

### View:

```
    <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
      <tr class="assignment-rows">
        <td><%= link_to assignment.name, account_assignment_path(assignment) %></td>
        <td><%= assignment.assigned_workers %></td>
        <td><%= assignment.status %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Error message:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draper Docs:
https://github.com/drapergem/draper

If you read the docs ;) and look at the `decorate_collection` section:
https://github.com/drapergem/draper#collections

which states:

> Note: In Rails 3, the .all method returns an array and not a query. Thus you cannot use the technique of Article.all.decorate in Rails 3. In Rails 4, .all returns a query so this techique would work fine.

So if you're using Rails 3 - you need to use `decorate_collection`... or you could (and probably should) upgrade to rails 4

Comment: Thanks for the help! couple things. I'm actually using Rails 5. and I tried using `decorate_collection` like the docs said but I keep getting this error 'uninitialized constant AssignmentDecorator::PagesController'

Comment: hmmm... interesting.  Did you follow the Draper directions on adding delegations for pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
@assignments = current_account.assignments.all.decorate
```

After

```
@assignments = current_account.assignments.decorate.all
```